# Adding a checkmark to fpdf file

Tags: fpdf

I am retrieving data from the database and I am displaying it using fpdf. I have a data with a value zero or one. If it is one, I want to display a checkmark. Is there a way to output a checkmark ?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

here's what I have tried but did not work. It actually stores the image in the folder instead of displaying it:

```
 $im = imagecreate( 200, 80 );

 $pdf->Cell(20,7, imagejpeg($im,"checkmark.jpg"));
```

Comment: why don't you just use a checkmark as an image and use the ->Image() method?

Comment: Any example on how to use it?

Comment: the Cell function doesn't take an image...it only takes text.

Comment: ok Image() works, thanks.